# How to center a WPF Window in a Excel VSTO addin

Tags: .net, wpf, vsto

The problem is that a WPF window only takes a system.form.window  so I cannot set Excel to be the owner object in my VSTO application, because the VSTO addin only exposes Excel's hwnd, or its active window as a Native Window since it is COM. That means when WindowStartUpLoadation is set to be center owner it doesn't work. So I am forced to work around this.

What I have come up with so far after reading [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/04/03/centering-wpf-windows-with-wpf-and-non-wpf-owner-windows.aspx) is to try and manually center the window, but even with his simple example my window never appears centered.

```
 private static void CenterWpfWindowInExcel(WpfParameterDialog wpfDialog)
    {
        WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfDialog);
        helper.Owner = new IntPtr(Globals.ExcelAddin.Application.Hwnd);


        // Manually calculate Top/Left to appear centered
        double nonWpfOwnerLeft = Globals.ExcelAddin.Application.ActiveWindow.Left; // Get non-WPF owner’s Left
        double nonWpfOwnerWidth = Globals.ExcelAddin.Application.ActiveWindow.Width; // Get non-WPF owner’s Width
        double nonWpfOwnerTop = Globals.ExcelAddin.Application.ActiveWindow.Top; // Get non-WPF owner’s Top
        double nonWpfOwnerHeight = Globals.ExcelAddin.Application.ActiveWindow.Height; // Get non-WPF owner’s Height
        wpfDialog.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
        wpfDialog.Left = nonWpfOwnerLeft + (nonWpfOwnerWidth - wpfDialog.Width)/2;
        wpfDialog.Top = nonWpfOwnerTop + (nonWpfOwnerHeight - wpfDialog.Height)/2;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.*

Comment: I edited it a bit to clarify my meaning, does it make more sense now? I am happy to elaborate on more specific details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this by get getting the Rect of the Main Excel Window  using `user32.dll`

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
```

It appears that Globals.ExcelAddin.Application.ActiveWindow was not giving me back the dimension I expected. I think it was giving me the Ribbon Addin's dimensions and not Excel's Main Window.